# Angular 2 add class and style to existing one from a JSON

Tags: angular

In our component, we retrieve through http a JSON containing various styling for our element:

```
{
  id: 1,
  style: "color: red; background-color: white;",
  class: "fa-times",
},
{
  id: 2,
  style: "",
  class: "fa-check active",
}
```

I can't really change the JSON retrieves as it's from an external source.

Then I want to apply that style in a ngFor loop:

```
<li *ngFor="let element of elements">
  <i class="fa" style=""></i> {{element .id}}
</li>
```

But now I want to add the classes and styles defined as strings in JSON into my element.

### Classes

I tried something like [class] = "fa {{element.class}}" but it triggers an error:

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: Parser Error: Got
>   interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 3 in [fa
>   {{element.class}}]

**I managed to get the class part of my request working** by using ngClass as suggered in some website and an answer here:

```
class="fa" [ngClass]="possibility.class"
```

It works. But I still struggle to apply requested styles.

### Styles

I tried several methods:

```
[style]="possibility.style"
```

It then triggers the xss protection of Angular2:

> WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value color: green (see
>   http://g.co/ng/security#xss).
>
> WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value color: green (see
>   http://g.co/ng/security#xss).
>
> WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value color: red (see
>   http://g.co/ng/security#xss).
>
> WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value color: red (see
>   http://g.co/ng/security#xss).

I also tried `style="{{possibility.style}}"` and of course it triggers the same XSS protection guard.

I tried the **ngStyle** method:

```
[ngStyle]="possibility.style"
```

But it seems not to be able to parse the style as it is parsed from JSON (e.g: string `color: green; background-color: white;`. Even a single style like `color: green;` breaks the script):

> Error in ./ProjectComponent class ProjectComponent - inline
>   template:15:14 caused by: Cannot find a differ supporting object
>   'color: green'
>
> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'color:
>   green'

Comment: I have lots of ways of doing this, but SO isn't a "do it for me" site. What approaches have you tried so far? What tools did you use? Have you read the docs for those tools? In what way(s) did things *not* work as expected? Do you have snippets of specific code that did not work?

Comment: Hi Peter, I updated the page to list all my attempts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ngClass](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html):

```
<li *ngFor="let element of elements">
  <i class="fa" [ngClass]="element.class"></i> {{element.id}}
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have the class attribute bind to a property of your component:

```
<i [class]="myProperyInMyComponent"></i> {{element .id}}
```

in your component:

```
myPropertyInMyComponent: string
```

once you get back the result from your http:

> this.myPropertyInMyComponent = ....

see [template syntax](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#other-bindings)